# Is it possible to add a C array of ints to an NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

I'm working with a 2D array of ints as a map format for a game. The horizontal length of the map doesn't change, but the vertical length can. Because of this, it seems that I should use the efficiency of C arrays for the actual data storage, and use an NSMutableArray for the container. However, I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Is it even possible to store a C array in an NSArray? I've tried various methods, but none seem to work.

Comment: Could there be some max length that the array will/should be? I'm thinking, why not just use the c array as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSArray only stores objects. You *could* define a custom NSArray subclass with an int array as data storage and special methods to store ints, and then box them (that is, convert the ints into NSNumbers) for NSArray's normal object interface — though that is *way* overly complicated for most purposes. But with plain NSArray, you're stuck with objects.

Comment: While Chuck's answer is correct, it's also probably a really bad idea. There are far simpler ways to store C arrays than using a custom NSArray subclass and going through the overhead of boxing/unboxing.

Comment: Just to be clear, I agree with @KevinBallard that this is not normally something you'd want to do. I can think of a few cases where you might, but generally not. I thought it was pretty clear that this was a rather complicated solution just for moving arrays around, but I'll edit the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only store objects in an `NSArray`. You could try storing an `NSMutableData` there which holds the bytes that backs your C array, but that's slightly awkward.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some of the C++ STL containers like the [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) This will have good performance as well as an interface for growing/shrinking the array as necessary.